# Using data.table's .() shortcut in quoted expressions

Tags: r, data.table, eval

I have some data.tables containing file names as a var named `fn`. I want to split off basename and extension:

```
library(data.table)
library(tools)

DT1 = data.table(fn = c("gah.csv", "egad.csv"))
DT2 = data.table(fn = c("gah.xlsx", "egad.xlsx"))
DT3 = data.table(fn = c("boo.txt", "ya.foo"))

do_split_fn = quote(c("name", "ext") := list(file_path_sans_ext(fn), file_ext(fn)))

DT1[, eval(do_split_fn)]
DT2[, eval(do_split_fn)]
DT3[, eval(do_split_fn)]
```

So this all works fine and my question is very minor: Can I use an expression more like this?

```
do_split_fn_dot = quote(c("name", "ext") := .(file_path_sans_ext(fn), file_ext(fn)))
DT1[, eval(do_split_fn_dot)]
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "."
```

That is, I'm trying to swap `list()` for `.()`, as one can do inside `` `[.data.table` ``.

My `quote`/`eval` stuff is an attempt at following [recommendations in the data.table FAQ 1.6](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#ok-but-i-dont-know-the-expressions-in-advance.-how-do-i-programatically-pass-them-in).

Comment: Maybe relevant, some context I posted to SO.Docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data.table/4456/using-list-columns-to-store-data/15561/reading-in-many-related-files#t=201612191733558301196 And, just to be clear, yes, I know this is an incredibly minor question I'm asking here.

Comment: I think of `.` as mainly for clarity/uncluttering... here, you're putting it in a `quote`d expression. Any reason not to just use `list`? (besides that it should just work)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Only to declutter the quoted expression itself.

Comment: You could always pre-alias: `. = list`

Comment: You might be able to get `substitute` to work, as it has an `env` argument.  But where is `.()` defined in the data.table namespace?  I don't see it in `ls(getNamespace("data.table"), all = TRUE)`

Comment: @Rich Scriven it looks like this is [handled internally](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L308-L316).

Comment: @MichaelChirico nrussell's link has an interesting source-code comment "we don't just simply alias `.=list` because i) list is a primitive (faster to iterate) and ii) we test for use of "list" in several places so it saves having to remember to write "." || "list" in those places "

Comment: Yep, that's what I had in mind when suggesting to alias -- for your case, neither of those concerns apply, I was thinking

Comment: @nrussell Nice find. I think that's a good answer, maybe something like `DT1 = data.table(fn = c("gah.csv", "egad.csv"));
dtq = function(x) data.table:::replace_dot_alias(substitute(x));
qq = dtq(c("name", "ext") := .(file_path_sans_ext(fn), file_ext(fn)));
DT1[, eval(qq)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already fixed

```r
library(data.table)
library(tools)

DT1 = data.table(fn = c("gah.csv", "egad.csv"))

do_split_fn_dot = quote(c("name", "ext") := .(file_path_sans_ext(fn), file_ext(fn)))
DT1[, eval(do_split_fn_dot)]
DT1
#         fn   name    ext
#1:  gah.csv    gah    csv
#2: egad.csv   egad    csv
```