# How is dot (.) alias for list constructor implemented in data.table package?

Tags: r, data.table

I wonder how is is the dot alias (`.`) for the `list` constructor function implemented in the `data.table` package. Just to be clear I am thinking about this functionality:

```
library(data.table)
D = data.table(iris)
x1 = D[, .(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)]    # dot alias
x2 = D[, list(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)] # standard name
identical(x1, x2)    # TRUE
```

I tried to find it in the source code on github, but it is too dense for me to understand it in any reasonable amount of time.

EDIT.
I know this can be easily done by defining an alias like: `. <- list` or `. <- function(...) list(...)`. However, this is not exactly what I am looking for. I want to define such an alias, so it only works in the context of a given function/method.

Example.

```
L <- .(1)   # This throws error
L <- func(.(1)) # This works
```

Actually I can get what I want using the `rlang` tools for tidy evaluation. Below is a simple example.

```
library(rlang)
func <- function(...) {
    . <- list
    eval_tidy(enexpr(x))
}
x1 <- func(.(1))
x2 <- list(1)
identical(x1, x2)   # TRUE
```

So I wonder how this kind of functionality is implemented in the `data.table` specifically, since it was developed a way earlier than `rlang`?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228076/using-data-tables-shortcut-in-quoted-expressions Data.table has some optimizations that are applied to expressions in `DT[...]` that you're likely to lose this way, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

data.table replaces the dot in expressions before they are evaluated. It uses computing on the language.

The relevant function is [`replace_dot_alias`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/search?q=replace_dot_alias&unscoped_q=replace_dot_alias) (note that reusing this function means that you need to conform to data.table's license):

```
replace_dot_alias = function(e) {
  # we don't just simply alias .=list because i) list is a primitive (faster to iterate) and ii) we test for use
  # of "list" in several places so it saves having to remember to write "." || "list" in those places
  if (is.call(e) && !is.function(e[[1L]])) {
    # . alias also used within bquote, #1912
    if (e[[1L]] == 'bquote') return(e)
    if (e[[1L]] == ".") e[[1L]] = quote(list)
    for (i in seq_along(e)[-1L]) if (!is.null(e[[i]])) e[[i]] = replace_dot_alias(e[[i]])
  }
  e
}
```

An example of usage:

```
expr <- quote(.(a = b, c = .(sum(d))))
replace_dot_alias(expr)
#list(a = b, c = list(sum(d)))
```

The modified expression is then executed.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly what I was looking for. For now I use in my application (that motivated my question) the approach based on `rlang` I described in the EDIT to my question. However, I am still not sure how is it so that `list` is faster (being a primitive) than an alias? Could you maybe elaborate a little bit more on that?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive